# configure Angular app with powers of deployUrl without using due to depreciation warning. (not baseHref)

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

In my Nx angular monorepo I want to have a deployUrl like implementation which can modify relative paths for module scripts.

Cannot use base-href as it changes routing paths also reloading causes 404 issues.

trying a post build script to achieve this but facing issues to modify runtimejs file.(not working)